# I need laravel website to open in https without public in url, how can I do it?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, environment-variables

I have created website on Laravel, so the website was being open under www.domain.com/public/. So I searched my answer here and found out this was working for me, after I added this code the page was opening at www.domain.com without public added to the url:

**htaccess:**

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now I installed SSL and I want to force it to open a page at https link but I dont know why it won't. I setted my APP URL inside .evn file to https link and added this code to the htacces file:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it now opens webpage every time in https but with additional public in url, when I try to delete public and set code to be:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It wont open my website at all. Please if anyone knows a fix to this I will be so much thankfull, best wishes!

Comment: Add this code `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: it gives me 403 forbidden error page

Comment: can you share your folder structure.. used in server

Comment: can you please be more specific, im kinda new to laravel, what folder structure? My root files are in resources/views/, public file is insite root public_html containing js/images/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this worked great! It replaced all my urls with the https one and it doesnt show public anymore, thanks bro

Comment: You have a great day too bro

Answer (score 1):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]